# How to color text in livecode

Tags: livecode

I need to color some text. myprefix is an array contain lot of prefix words and i colored the prefix words in myHtml. But i want to color the next word (example : "under some". here under is the prefix, i need to color both words under and some. I passed to color the prefix term.

```
put the field Prefix into myPrefix
   split myPrefix by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myPrefix) into myLen
   repeat with p = 1 to myLen 
      put myPrefix[p] into v
            if pre is empty then
         put the  0 into q
         else
         replace v with "<font bgcolor=" & quote & "lightblue" & quote & ">" & v & "</font>" in myHtml 
               end if
         end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere else, you have a similar script, which also uses an array where you really shouldn't use an array. This is another example of such a case. Just don't use an array here, but do a loop over the lines of the list.

```
  put field "Prefix" into myPrefix
     repeat for each line v in myPrefix
          if pre is empty then
               put the  0 into q
          else
               replace v with "<font bgcolor=" & quote & "lightblue" & quote & ">" & v & "</font>" in myHtml 
          end if
     end repeat
```

Comment: I want to color both the prefix(v) and the next word followed with the perfix.

Comment: Please put an sample of the actual data you're using in your question.

Comment: eg:- "Iam a pre editor". in this line, i need to color both pre and editor. Here pre is the prefix and editor is the word followed to it

Comment: Yes, I think this can be done with regex. I'll look into it when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you transform your field text into an array? Why not just color the words of interest in the field itself:

```
set the foreColor of word 3 of line 4 of fld "prefix" to "red"
```

Comment: because i have lot of prefix terms in the array